# A dummies guide to installing a PhoneGap plugin

Tags: npm, phonegap

I am trying to build a basic QR code scanning app but I am not exactly sure how to add a plugin. I am trying to install - https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-barcodescanner

I have installed NPM, GIT and Cordova, and have deployed a Framework 7 based app from the phonegap software that has the following directory:

C:\Users\user\Documents\Phonegap Apps\Saving Energy\Android

[image]

I am unsure how to install the plugin? Do I run

```
npm i cordova-plugin-barcodescanner
```

in Windows Command Prompt, and if so do I have to change the directory to my app plugin folder? Do I run it using node.js? Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add plugin easily using cordova

you should open command prompt with Saving Energy as directory and run

```
cordova plugin add [cordova-plugin-name]
```

For your case it is

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-barcodescanner
```

Hope it Helps!